# How to filter groupby for first N items

Tags: python, pandas

In Pandas, how can I modify `groupby` to only take the first N items in the group?

**Example**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2], 
                   'values': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]})
>>> df
   id  values
0   1       1
1   1       2
2   1       3
3   2       4
4   2       5
5   2       6
6   2       7
```

**Desired functionality**

```
# This doesn't work, but I am trying to return the first two items per group.
>>> df.groupby('id').first(2)  
   id  values
0   1       1
1   1       2
3   2       4
4   2       5
```

**What I've tried**

I can perform a groupby and iterate through the groups to take the index of the first `n` values, but there must be a simpler solution.

```
n = 2  # First two rows.
idx = [i for group in df.groupby('id').groups.itervalues() for i in group[:n]]
>>> df.ix[idx]
   id  values
0   1       1
1   1       2
3   2       4
4   2       5
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`head`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.head.html):

```
In [11]: df.groupby("id").head(2)
Out[11]:
   id  values
0   1       1
1   1       2
3   2       4
4   2       5
```

*Note: In older versions this used to be equivalent to `.apply(pd.DataFrame.head)` but it's more efficient since 0.15 (?), now it uses [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) under the hood.*

Comment: That is the simpler answer I was looking for.  Thanks.

Comment: @Alexander some of these seem hidden (mainly since there's sooo many methods), related are tail and nth.